# Capture stdout to variable and get the exit statuses of foreground pipe

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout, exit-code

I want to execute a command (say `ls`) and `sed` its output, then save the stdout to a variable, like this,

```
OUT=$(ls | sed -n -e 's/regexp/replacement/p')
```

After this, if I try to access the [`$PIPESTATUS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIPESTATUSREF) array, I get only `0` (which is same as `$?`). So, how can I get both `$PIPESTATUS` as well as capture the entire piped command's stdout?

Note:

- If I only executed those piped commands and didn't capture the stdout (like `ls | sed -n -e 's/regexp/replacement/p'`), I get expected exit statuses in `$PIPESTATUS` (like `0 0`)
- If I only executed single command (without piping multiple commands) using [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and captured the stdout (like `OUT=$(ls)`), I get expected **single** exit status in `$PIPESTATUS` (which is same as `$?`)

P.S. I know, I could run the command 2 times (first to capture the stdout, second to access `$PIPESTATUS` without using Command Substitution), but is there a way to get both in single execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Use a temporary file to pass PIPESTATUS.

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   out=$(pipeline; echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" > "$tmp")
   PIPESTATUS=($(<"$tmp"))  # Note: PIPESTATUS is overwritten each command...
   rm "$tmp"
   ```
2. Use a temporary file to pass `out`.

   ```
   tmp=$(mktemp)
   pipeline > "$tmp"
   out=$(<"$tmp"))
   rm "$tmp"
   ```
3. Interleave output with pipestatus. For example reserve the part from last newline character till the end for PIPESTATUS. To preserve original return status I think some temporary variables are needed:

   ```
   out=$(pipeline; tmp=("${PIPESTATUS[@]}") ret=$?; echo $'\n' "${tmp[@]}"; exit "$ret"))
   pipestatus=(${out##*$'\n'})
   out="${out%$'\n'*}"
   out="${out%%$'\n'}" # remove trailing newlines like command substitution does
   ```

   tested with:

   ```
   out=$(false | true | false | echo 123; echo $'\n' "${PIPESTATUS[@]}");
   pipestatus=(${out##*$'\n'});
   out="${out%$'\n'*}"; out="${out%%$'\n'}";
   echo out="$out" PIPESTATUS="${pipestatus[@]}"
   # out=123 PIPESTATUS=1 0 1 0
   ```

Notes:

- Upper case variables by convention should be reserved by exported variables.